# Method Overriding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw this particular piece of code:

```
def g(x,y):
    return x+y
def g(x,y):
    return x*y
x,y=6,7
print (g(x,y))
```

The output is obviously(but not to me) is 42. Can somebody please explain this behavior? This is method overriding I suppose, but I'm still not getting the flow here.

Comment: What would you expect it to be?

Comment: What I meant was why is it getting overridden? Why the answer isn't just 13? There is no inheritance going on here,right?

Comment: when you defined a function g. it is stored in a variable named `g`. When you define a new function with the same name, this variable get replaced. Try `print(id(g))` to see that the variable reference is changed

Comment: What I don't get is after it got the value 13 & returned it, why would it go on looking for *another* g. The value is returned, why not print it right there, why is the other one getting called even?

Comment: You never get the value 13 in this example. The fist function is never called

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but then why is the first one getting *skipped*? Is it because of Python code flow or anything?

Comment: for the same reason that  `a = 1 ;  a = 2 ; a == 2 -> True`. The code is evaluated from top to bottom

Comment: But in your example also `a` is assigned the value 1 first,right? Then its overridden? Is this what you're trying to say or have I got it horribly wrong?

Comment: Yup. Defining a function essentially assigns a function object to a variable of the same name. So defining a new function with the same name, is equal to assigning a new function object to that variable

Comment: Okay, now I get it, Thanks

Comment: I would not use the term "overriding" though because it is re-assignment or probably shadowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a function, and you redefine it, it will use the last one you defined, even the parameter is different:

```
def g(x,y):
    return x+y
def g(x,y):
    return x*y
x,y=6,7
print (g(x,y))

def hello():
    return 'hello'
def hello():
    return 'bye'

print hello()

def withone(word):
    return word

def withone():
    return 1==1

print withone('ok')
```

Output:

```
42
bye
TypeError: withone() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

And function name in Python is more like simple variable:

```
def hello():
    return 'hello'

iamhello = hello # bind to the old one

def hello():
    return 'bye'

print hello() # here is the new guy

print iamhello()
```

OutPut:

```
bye
hello
```

Comment: How is the `withone` example related to this?

Comment: Forgive me forgot add parameter.

Comment: This example gave error: `TypeError: withone() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: That typo furthers shows that the old function that takes a parameter is gone :)

Comment: Yes, because the last definition take no parameter,so you can not use it.You redefine it without a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The devil is in the order of function definitions.

This is not technically method overriding as that requires class inheritance, instead it's a result of how python declares and references functions.

When declaring a function, python stores a reference to that function in a variable named after the function definition. (e.g. variable would be "foo" for "def foo():")

By declaring the function twice, the value of that variable gets overwritten by the second definition.

Answer (score 1):

A Python script is parsed from top till bottom. 
So anytime the same name of a variable or function or class occurs, it overwrites any definitions that where associated with this name before.

```
def g(x,z):
    print('first')

def g():
    print('second')

g = 3
print g
print g()
```

So look at this example which will result in the printout of '3' and then in an Exception: `'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable'`

The name g is at first a function with two parameters, then it gets redefined to be a function with no parameters, then it gets redefined to be an int.
Which cannot be called obviously :)

Comment: So, there's no concept for method overloading here?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in python is treated as object, whether it be a function name or class name. So, when we define a function using `'def'`, the memory allocation is done for that method. Then python points the name that we assign to the function, to this allocated memory location. So if we define a method :-

```
def demo():
    print 'hi'
```

the memory is allocated for the method, and the name `'demo'` is pointed to its memory location as follows :-

[image]

Now as described by [zoosuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104689/method-overriding/28104735#28104735) in his second example, when you assign the function name to another variable :-

```
demo2 = demo # bind to the old one
```

then in that case, the assigned memory location to `demo`, is assigned to `demo2` as well. So both `demo` and `demo2` points to same location `12506`.

```
print id(demo)   # will print 12506
print id(demo2)  # will print 12506
```

[image]

Now if we modify the above piece of code and in the next line, define a new method with same name `demo`:-

```
def demo():
    print 'hi'

demo2 = demo # bind to the old one
demo()       # Will print hi

def demo():
    print "hello"

demo()      # Will print hello
demo2()     # Will print hi
```

then a completely new memory location `12534` is allocated for this new method, and now `demo` will point to this new location `12534` instead of pointing to the old one i.e. to `12506`. But `demo2` is still pointing to the location `12506`.

[image]

I hope this will give you a clear idea of what is going on and how the method name is over-written.

Answer (score 0):

Order matters, if names are same,last function you defined is processing. In your case it's;

```
def g(x,y):
    return x*y
```

Answer (score 0):

`g` is just a variable. The fact that the object it refers to is a function doesn't make it special in Python, so you can assign and reassign it as you want. In this case, the second assignment (which is what a function definition is) simply replaces the object stored there with a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Functions and methods are normal objects like any others. So in

```
def g(x, y):
    return x + y

def g(x, y):
    return x * y
```

the second object `g` will override(replace) the first one, just like object `a` does below:

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

The number, type or order of parameters does not make any difference, because Python does not support function/method override and does not allow two functions/methods to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), also often called anonymous\inline functions, this might clear things up a bit

These two code blocks are essentially equal

```
def g(x,y):
    return x+y
def g(x,y):
    return x*y
```

---

```
g = lambda x,y:  x+y
g = lambda x,y:  x*y
```